# tikz in table with right colored arrows and xshift and y shift

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-arrows

I have the following code as can be seen below the images. The output I have now is like the first image below.

[image: current output]

I want the output to be as in the image below with blue and red arrows in the middle. I can't seem to manage to change the colors and the placement of the arrows.
[image: required output]

The code is below. Can anyone help me out?

```
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
V   & M   & V   & M   & V   & M   \\ \hline
6   & 4  & NaN & NaN & NaN & NaN \\ \hline
7   & 3   & 5   & 5 \tikzmark{f}   & NaN & NaN \\ \hline
NaN & NaN & 8   & \tikzmark{d}{2} \tikzmark{e}  & \tikzmark{c}{4}   &     \tikzmark{b}{6}   \\ \hline
NaN & NaN & NaN & NaN & 10  & \tikzmark{a}{0}   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shorten >=.5pt, shorten <=.5pt]
\draw [->] ({pic cs:a}) [line width=0.35mm, yshift=-1] to ({pic cs:b});
\draw [->] ({pic cs:c}) [line width=0.35mm, yshift=-1] to ({pic cs:d});
\draw [->] ({pic cs:e}) [line width=0.35mm, yshift=-1] to ({pic cs:f});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Hmmm... for the color, `\draw[red, ->] ...` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using `\tikzmark` I would use a `matrix of math nodes` inside a tikz `\matrix`. As you are drawing your entries inside a tabular environment, changing to using a `matrix of math nodes` actually simplifies the code.

I will give the output, the code and then explain how it works. First, the output:

[image]

Next the code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=2pt,looseness=.5,auto]
    \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,row sep=0mm,column sep=0mm,
                nodes=draw, minimum size=12mm]{
        V   & M   & V   & M   & V   & M   \\
        6   & 4   & NaN & NaN & NaN & NaN \\
        7   & 3   & 5   & 5   & NaN & NaN \\
        NaN & NaN & 8   & 2   &  4  &  6  \\
        NaN & NaN & NaN & NaN & 10  &  0  \\
     };
    \draw[ultra thick,blue,->] (M-5-6.west) -- (M-4-6.west);
    \draw[ultra thick,red,->]  (M-5-5.north) -- (M-5-4.north);
    \draw[ultra thick,blue,->] (M-4-4.west) -- (M-3-4.west);
    \draw[ultra thick,red,->]  (M-4-3.north) -- (M-4-2.north);
    \draw[ultra thick,blue,->] (M-3-2.west) -- (M-2-2.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now the explanation:

The  `\matrix (M)` command sets up a matrix with coordinates specified by `(M-<row>-<col>)`, where `<row>` and `<col>` are the row and column indices. If you instead wrote `\matrix (mat)` then you would refer to the coordinates as `(mat-<row>-<col>)`.

Next, you can use `north`, `south`, `west`, `north west` etc to adjust which part of the matrix cell the node specification refers to. For example, `(M-4-3.west)` refers to the western edge of the node in row 4 and column 3. Almost everything should now be clear, I hope!

In the `matrix of math nodes` I have set `row sep=0mm,column sep=0mm, nodes=draw, minimum size=12mm`. This is to draw your grid: there are no gaps between the rows and the columns, each node should have a rectangle drawn around it and the minimum cell size of `12m` was chosen so as to fit the contents of the OP's cells. Personally, I would not draw the grid (the documentation of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package explains why you should avoid vertical lines in tables), but it was what the question asked for so....

If you want the layout to be the same as in your MWE, with rectangular cells rather than the square cells in my code then change the `minimum size=12mm` to `minimum width=12mm`. To show what this looks like, and to further highlight the node specs, if you change the draw statements to

```
    \draw[ultra thick,blue,->] (M-5-6.south west) -- (M-4-6.south west);
    \draw[ultra thick,red,->]  (M-5-5.north east) -- (M-5-4.north west);
    \draw[ultra thick,blue,->] (M-4-4.south west) -- (M-3-4.south west);
    \draw[ultra thick,red,->]  (M-4-3.north east) -- (M-4-2.north west);
    \draw[ultra thick,blue,->] (M-3-2.south west) -- (M-2-2.south west);
```

then with `minimum size=12mm` you get

[image]

**EDIT** (answering questions in the comments)

To shade the columns it is enough to add the following `every odd column` and `every even column` styles to the matrix options:

```
every odd column/.style={nodes={fill=pink}},
every even column/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20!white}},
```

With these in place your picture becomes:

[image]

The "double" lines that you are seeing are, I believe, rendering errors and are probably browser dependent and they perhaps do not appear when printing (I don't know, I haven't checked). For the picture above I eliminated them in a very *ad hoc* way by changing the row and column separations to:

```
row sep=-0.1mm,column sep=-0.1mm
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Can you tell me why there are some double lines between the lines? Like in de upper left corner there are double horizontal lines between V M and  6 4 cells? Also is there a way to give the columns a color? I want the M columns to be light blue and the V column to be pink.

Comment: @michAmir You really should ask another question! :) See my edit.